# Script to delete older files and copy what is left

Tags: linux, centos, bash, scripting, rsync

We have a server that runs an application that is used internally.  The application has a utility that creates its own backups every 24 hours.

Backups are stored in: /var/application/application-data/exports

We have a NFS mount under /mnt/AppDataBkp

I would like to set up a bash script to do the following:

1. On a schedule (cron, every 24hrs), it will look for any .zip files in var/application/application-data/exports older than 7 days and remove them.
2. Then, it will copy whatever it is left in that directory to /mnt/AppDataBkp
3. Optionally, it would be nice if it could also remove any files/backups from /mnt/AppDataBkp older than 7 days.

So far, I've come up with this which is supposed to find files older than 7 days and delete them:

```
#!/bin/bash

find var/application/application-data/exports -name "*.zip" -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
rsync -rlptgoD /var/application/application-data/exports /mnt/AppDataBkp &&
find /mnt/AppDataBkp -name "*.zip" -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How does this fail to achieve what you want ?

Comment: I think it *should* work, but I wanted to confirm. Also, is there an option/switch for rsync when it's done copying over stuff from source to automatically delete files on the destination which are no longer in the source folder?  For example if i remove text1.txt from the source folder, can I get rsync to automatically remove it at the destination next time it runs? That way I don't have to run the find command again.

Comment: You need to test it rather than getting someone to tell you it'll work. You may want to look into the `touch` command. While you're at it look at the documentation for rsync - you'll find something usefull there too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As simple as:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ----Starting Backup----
echo Start Time: $(date +%m-%d-%Y) $(date +%H-%M)
echo ------------------------
echo Deleting if older than 7 days
echo ------------------------
find /var/application/application-data/exports/*.zip -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
echo ------------------------
echo Sending to AppDataBkp
echo ------------------------
rsync -rlptgoD /var/application/application-data/exports /mnt/AppDataBkp
echo ------------------------
echo Deleting if older than 7 days in AppDataBkp
echo ------------------------
find /mnt/AppDataBkp/*.zip -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
echo ------------------------
echo ----Backup Complete----
```

Answer (score 1):

My help would be to use `-delete` instead of the `exec rm ...`

Comment: Any particular reason?